# How to build a umd version of material-ui?

Tags: requirejs, material-ui, amd, umd

The material-ui "build:es2015" script is building commonjs scripts, not ES2015.
    'use strict';

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

etc.
```

I'm trying to find a way to build an AMD-friendly version of material-ui similar to https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html#using-a-cdn.

With ES2015 I should be able to compile with typescript into an AMD bundle.  The source files look very close to typescript files, but changing the extension to TSX isn't enough...they're not actually typescript files (what are they?).

Also, I tried the "build:umd:dev" doesn't produce anything so nice as https://unpkg.com/react@16.2.0/umd/react.development.js, and they seem incompatible with requirejs.

What are the necessary steps to building a true umd version of material-ui?

Background:
Yes, I know traditional react development process uses webpack but I'm trying to produce a light-weight, CDN-dependent proof-of-concept app that runs from rawgit.  I have the react and react-dom parts working but not the material-ui.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        @import url('app.css');
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <app/>
    <script>
        requirejs.config({
            // module name mapped to CDN url
            paths: {
                'react': 'https://unpkg.com/react@16.2.0/umd/react.production.min',
                'react-dom': 'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min',
                'openlayers': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/4.5.0/ol',
            },
            deps: ['built/index'],
            callback: () => require(["index"], go => console.log("app", go()))
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

A UMD build is published for every release.

For example: https://unpkg.com/material-ui@1.0.0-beta.24/umd/

Note: with version 4, the UMD output will be renamed as `MaterialUI` (previously `material-ui`).  See this [pull-request](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/13142) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I like [TypeScript Namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) for prototyping to and had already created separate UMD distribution **with typing for global object extension**

> Check source code and example app [here](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/material-ui-umd/blob/master/packages/form-generator-app/src/main.tsx).

```
namespace app {

  const {
    Button,
  } = material.core;

  const App = () => <Button>Hello, world!</Button>

  ...
```

Also I wrote some tools which help you make your app npm-independent includes router, snack provider, state manager, JSON template form generator, fetch provider, date and time pickers.

[image]

Amazing project. English translation will be applied soon so a star will be appreciated

[image]